# Angular: How to pass an inline style to component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have created a custom component. The component's HTML scaffolding contains very simple HTML.

```
<!-- Generated template for the MyComponent component -->
<div>
  {{text}}
</div>
```

But adding a style like this did not work.

```
<my-component style="height:300px; background:gray;"></my-component>
```

I think I need to pass that style to the `<div>`. But how?

Comment: its the component inside of a loop?

Comment: Custom Angular components by default miss the `display: block` - could you try adding it to the style and check if this resolves your issue?

Comment: is just doing it in the component template `<div style="height:300px; background:gray;">{{text}}</div>` a bad idea?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: If I add the style in the component itself, and I put two instances of that component on the page, wouldn't the two look the same? I want the two to look different. So, I want to supply the style from the page. The component is not inside a loop.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try (as already mentioned by @1.618)

```
<my-component [ngStyle]="{height:'300px', background:'gray', display: 'block'}">
</my-component>
```

applying only style (with `display: block` or `inline-block`) will also work:

```
<hello style="color: green; height:200px; background:yellow; display: block;" 
       name="Another name"></hello>
```

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hy6xpc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Variable/Prop inside the styling like this:

```
<button [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: variableNameOrPropNameHere}">{{text}}</button>
```

Note, you can also MIX them in the same code:

```
<button style="padding: 10px" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: variableNameOrPropNameHere}">{{text}}</button>
```

because default inline styling is a bit standard and faster to type and is similar to standard CSS, while ngStyle is more like React inline styling.

Just to have couple of options  =)